# Is there a way to only play audio from a video?

Tags: java, javafx, vlcj

I want to play a downloaded talk show, but I only want to play audio. Whenever I do `MediaPlayer.media().play("video.mp4")`, it opens the video in a pop-up window. Is there a way to hide that window, or to disable video track if needed?

I've tried setting renderer to null, but it doesn't do anything

```
mediaPlayer.setRenderer(null);
```

```
String url = "video.mp4";
mediaPlayer.media().play(url);
```

I'd like to only play Audio from a video, but I always get a pop-up playing video track.

Comment: I don't see this with the `AudioBarChartApp` in Ensemble.

Comment: Renderer is for things like Chromecast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with custom VLC switches passed as media player factory arguments:

```
MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory("--novideo");
AudioMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayer = new AudioMediaPlayerComponent(factory);
```

You don't need to use `AudioMediaPlayerComponent`, it just happens to be the most convenient.

Comment: Oooh, that makes it a lot easier. Thanks